# How to select sub string in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I have a scenario where my data is something like below:

> Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16

- Case 1 : I want to select  Chapter 18 from the above string.
- Case 2 : I want to select  Unit 10 from the above string.
- Case 3 : I want to select  Sect 16 from the above string.

Comment: are numbers constant? could it be `chapter 45 unit 145 sect 2`? How about case sensitive?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many, many similar questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using substr:

```
declare
  l_start number := DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time;
begin
for i in (
with t as (
  select 'Chapter ' || level || ' Unit ' || level || ' Sect ' || level  d from dual connect by rownum < 100000
)
select substr(d, 1, instr(d, ' ', 1, 2) - 1) chapter
     , substr(d, 
          instr(d, ' ', 1, 2), 
          instr(d, ' ', 1, 4) - instr(d, ' ', 1, 2)
       ) unit
     , substr(d, 
          instr(d, ' ', 1, 4), 
          length(d) - instr(d, ' ', 1, 4) + 1
       ) sect 
  from t
)
loop
  null;
end loop;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line((DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time - l_start) || ' hsec');
end;

126 hsec
```

Using regexp:

```
declare
  l_start number := DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time;
begin
for i in (
with t as (
  select 'Chapter ' || level || ' Unit ' || level || ' Sect ' || level  d from dual connect by rownum < 100000
)
select regexp_substr(d, 'Chapter [0-9]*') chapter
     , regexp_substr(d, 'Unit [0-9]*') unit
     , regexp_substr(d, 'Sect [0-9]*') sect 
  from t
)
loop
  null;
end loop;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line((DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time - l_start) || ' hsec');
end;

190 hsec
```

So the solution with regexp is slower, but it is more readable, if I were you I would use regexp.

Comment: That is completely wrong test case. Your REGEXP query doesn't use the column 'd', rather you have just hardcoded 'Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16'. Just replace it with column d and see the difference. I will edit my post to add your test case to prove my statement that REGEXP will be slower and will consume  more resources.

Comment: In the new update, perhaps you copy pasted the substr code in the regexp, so both are same codes. You might have to edit again.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)), with right regular expressions. For example:

```
select regexp_substr('Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16', 'Chapter \d*') from dual;
  --Will return: Chapter 18
select regexp_substr('Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16', 'Unit \d*') from dual;
  --Will return: Unit 10
select regexp_substr('Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16', 'Sect \d*') from dual;
  --Will return: Sect 16
```

Of course if you store `Chapter xx Unit yy Sect zz` strings in table, then you simply use this kind of query to get multiple results:

```
select regexp_substr(info_column, 'Chapter \d*') from mytable;
```

You can replace `\d` with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`

**[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34977/0)**

Comment: No problem with regular expressions until you encounter issues with high CPU resource consumption. I would rather use old SUBSTR for such simple requirement.

Comment: Of course I would suggest normal `substr` if the values in the string in question would always be two-digit.

Comment: See my update. I have shown REGEXP is slower using zaratustra's test case. His test case was incorrect and when corrected it shows the new execution times to prove the fact.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the old SUBSTR rather than REGEXP. Since REGEXP will take up too much CPU resource.

Your requirement is quite simple.

For data as `Chapter 18 Unit 10 Sect 16`, if you want Chapter 18 as output :

Just execute :

`Select substr(column, 1, 10) from table`

Similarly, you can do for other outputs.

Edit : Folks, some of you might think why am I stressing on good old SUBSTR over REGEXP. Just put trace on, and look at the trace output. I agree, with newer versions, Oracle has made a lot of improvement to REGEXP. But, till date I haven't seen a case where I got satisfied. I might be wrong, so, if anyone has a test case, I would really like to see it. It would a good learning for all of us.

**Update to show the above test case about REGULAR EXPRESSION faster than SUBSTR + INSTR, is wrong!**

**REGULAR EXPRESSION :**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      l_start NUMBER := dbms_utility.get_cpu_time;
  3  BEGIN
  4      FOR i IN (WITH t
  5                     AS (SELECT 'Chapter '
  6                                || LEVEL
  7                                || ' Unit '
  8                                || LEVEL
  9                                || ' Sect '
 10                                || LEVEL d
 11                         FROM   dual
 12                         CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 100000)
 13                SELECT Regexp_substr(d, 'Chapter [0-9]*') chapter,
 14                       Regexp_substr(d, 'Unit [0-9]*')    unit,
 15                       Regexp_substr(d, 'Sect [0-9]*')    sect
 16                 FROM   t) LOOP
 17          NULL;
 18      END LOOP;
 19
 20      dbms_output.Put_line('time taken by REGULAR EXPRESSION : '
 21                           || ( dbms_utility.get_cpu_time - l_start )
 22                           || ' hsec');
 23  END;
 24
 25  /
time taken by REGULAR EXPRESSION : 61 hsec

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**SUBSTR + INSTR :**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      l_start NUMBER := dbms_utility.get_cpu_time;
  3  BEGIN
  4      FOR i IN (WITH t
  5                     AS (SELECT 'Chapter '
  6                                || LEVEL
  7                                || ' Unit '
  8                                || LEVEL
  9                                || ' Sect '
 10                                || LEVEL d
 11                         FROM   dual
 12                         CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 100000)
 13                SELECT Substr(d, 1, Instr(d, ' ', 1, 2) - 1)
 14                       chapter,
 15                       Substr(d, Instr(d, ' ', 1, 2),
 16                       Instr(d, ' ', 1, 4) - Instr(d,
 17                       ' ', 1, 2))
 18                       unit,
 19                       Substr(d, Instr(d, ' ', 1, 4), Length(d) - Instr(d, ' ', 1,
 20                                                                  4)
 21                                                      + 1)
 22                       sect
 23                 FROM   t) LOOP
 24          NULL;
 25      END LOOP;
 26
 27      dbms_output.Put_line('time taken by SUBSTR + INSTR : '
 28                           || ( dbms_utility.get_cpu_time - l_start )
 29                           || ' hsec');
 30  END;
 31
 32  /
time taken by SUBSTR + INSTR : 28 hsec

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**So, it can be clearly seen SUBSTR + INSTR took less  than half the  time that of REGULAR EXPRESSION.**

Comment: As long as the numbers are always two digits, and the elements are always in that order. Not sure that's clear from the question. ("something like..." is always a bit of a concern!). Regex is more flexible, but obviously potentially at a cost.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. REGEXP beats SUBSTR + INSTR dramatically.

Comment: @zaratustra, Sure, let me have a look and test it.

Comment: @Alex, I don't hate regular expressions. Just that I don't like their performance in batch processes or on OLTP systems. They are so much resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

My version, useful when the data length is NOT fixed.! This might be bit **generic**

Last argument to the `regexp_substr` actually returns the corresponding case result!

```
SELECT level as case ,
       regexp_substr('Chapter 180 Unit 10 Sect 16 World 100', '\w* \d*( )*',1,level) as result
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(regexp_count('Chapter 180 Unit 10 Sect 16 World 100',' ')/2)
```

**Result:**

```
      CASE RESULT
---------- ------------------------
         1 Chapter 180
         2 Unit 10
         3 Sect 16
         4 World 100
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34978)

Comment: They may not be OLTP transactions friendly, but really flexible!

Comment: Flexible, yes. Resource hungry, yes :-)

Comment: Yes Bro! usually these kind requirements could be in DW.. I use it often. Not online. And my oracle is hosted over `EXADATA` .. resource abuse, we never heard of from DBA.. we see only under usage :p

Comment: Lucky guy to be on `EXADATA`, lol!

Anyway, my only concern is that the answered marked as correct is demonstrating an incorrect test case.