# Oracle SQL Split by Delimiters Without Store Procedure/Function

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I want to split a column by delimiters (|) in oracle db. How can i do that?

In db the value will be stored as:

Field

```
AP1|Apple Juice|100
```

I want to separate it become:

Field1 | Field2 |Field3

```
AP1 Apple Juice 100
```

I dont know the exact query for that but basically below is what i want.

```
select split(Field) as Field1, split(Field) as Field2, split(Field) as Field3
```

I wanted to use just SQL (without creating  any store procedure or function).

Comment: There are various different solutions in the post I've identified.  Choose the one which fits your version and other needs.  Probably the SQL with regex solution is the easiest to implement.  (All the solutions use `,` as the delimiter so replace that with `|`).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, i wanted to use just query (without any creation of store procedure, functions), but the given examples used it.

Comment: Okay, I've re-opened it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regex :

```
with sample_data as
    (select 'AP1|Apple Juice|100' str
    from dual
)
select str,
     regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 1) str1,
     regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 2) str2,
     regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 3) str3
from sample_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in pure **SQL** using **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** to extract the substrings between the delimiter `|`.

For simple string manipulation, I prefer `SUBSTR + INSTR` approach as it is [**still faster than the REGEXP**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768553/3989608). Of course with recent releases, the performance difference is decreasing, however, REGEXP is still more CPU intensive than the old `SUBTR+INSTR`.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS
  2    (SELECT 'AP1|Apple Juice|100' str
  3    FROM dual
  4    )
  5  -- end of sample_data mocking as a table
  6  SELECT str,
  7         SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '|', 1,1) -1) str1,
  8         SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
  9                   instr(str, '|', 1, 2) -
 10                  instr(str, '|', 1, 1) -1) str2,
 11         SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '|', 1, 2) + 1) str3
 12  FROM sample_data;

STR                 STR1                STR2                STR3
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ----
AP1|Apple Juice|100 AP1                 Apple Juice         100
```

On a side note, you should not store data as **delimited string**, it is really a bad design. You should **normalize** it as a **permanent fix**. As far as possible, store the **attributes** in **different columns**, then you do not have the overhead of manipulating the string to extract respective attributes.

Comment: Using the plain good old `instr()`+`substr()` combo in these days full of regexp's. I like this answer.

Comment: @nop77svk Yeah, it depends. This was  a simple test case.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah realized that it is not a good design.

Comment: @user3172596 Also, understand when and where to use REGEXP as it is not going to be better in terms of performance on a large data set with such denormalized data.